# How raster files are stored in databases?

Tags: postgresql, postgis-raster, storage

When storing raster files in PostgreSQL only one row is created in the database, but the raster is a **matrix** so typically it must create rows and columns.

I want to understand how raster files are stored in databases?

Comment: Have you already read this https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRaster/Documentation01?

Comment: Yes I read it but I think that the explanation isn't clear

Comment: Can you clarify, are you asking just about PostgreSQL (tags/body), or is the question wider, for example what about the storage of rasters in array databases such as [Rasdaman](http://www.rasdaman.com)